# Dispose all IDisposables when exiting the method without using?

Tags: c#, idisposable

Perhaps I am too lazy, but nested `using`s in a method make the method look complicated and difficult to understand. Is there any way to make all `IDisposable` objects that were created in a method be automatically disposed when exiting the method due to an exception?

---

PS. Thank you for the feedback. I now know there is no such feature right now. But, theoretically, is the following hypothetical syntax plausible?

```
void SomeMethod()
{
     autodispose var com = new SQLCommand();
     ...
     autodispose var file = new FileStream();
     ....
     autodispose var something = CreateAnObjectInAMethod(); 
     ....
}
```

All three objects are automatically disposed when exiting the method for any reason.

Comment: You shouldn't have too much nested usings in one method, otherwise consider to change the architecture of your method. The Using statement was created to avoid manually disposing calls and it looks way cleaner.

Comment: It doesn't matter if he likes the syntax or not, there's no better and cleaner way of doing it so if he thinks nested `using`s is cluttered the alternatives are way worse.

Comment: What you are asking isn't possible without wrapping them all in using statements. If you really don't want to use using statements then you may be able to do something with PostSharp but I've not used it much so I'm not sure. https://www.postsharp.net/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No but you can tidy a bit like so...

This...

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection("blah"))
{
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("blah"))
    {
        using (var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Becomes...

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection("blah"))
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("blah"))
using (var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{

}
```